# Is AOT compilation supported in JDK10?

Tags: java, aot, java-10

From [JEP-295](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295), it states:

> AOT compilation of any JDK modules, classes, or of user code, is
>   experimental and not supported in JDK 9.

I cannot find anything about Java 10.

Is AOT compilation (jaotc) supported in JDK10?

Comment: Currently only 12 JEPs are part of JDK10. None of those deal with AOT compilation.

Answer (score 4):

> Note: Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation is an experimental feature and
>   is supported only on Linux-x64.

JDK 10 Documentation, Java Platform, Standard Edition [Java Virtual Machine Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/vm/java-hotspot-virtual-machine-performance-enhancements.htm#JSJVM-GUID-F33D8BD0-5C4A-4CE8-8259-FD9D73C7C7C6)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something but as far as I can tell when you install JDK `10.0.1` for windows 64 you will get the `jaotc.exe` as part of the JDK installation. That doesn't seem to match the other answers. Feel free to correct me

Comment: They are providing the executable; however, if it is experimental and unsupported (as JEP-295 says it is for JDK 9 [hence the JDK10 question]), then I don't want to spend my time integrating it into by application development.

Answer (score 1):

The AOT feature is not part of the [Java 10 release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/10-relnote-issues-4108729.html). It is also not listet in the Java 10 documentation. So AOT is not a official part of Java 10.

The `jaotc` tool was only a part of the Linux release of Java 9. In Java 10 it is also a part of the MacOS release.

Comment: Windows has `jaotc` as well